# How to compile this code?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Could somebody teach me how to compile this code?

```
Do[uu = Outer[Times, u[[n1]], u[[m1]]];
   Unm[[n1, m1]] = Flatten[uu].Flatten[data], {n1, n}, {m1,  n}]; 
Do[uuu = Outer[Times, u[[All, s]], u[[All, t]]];
   reimg[[s, t]] = Flatten[uuu].Flatten[Unm], {s, sz}, {t,  sz}];
```

This part of code calculates image moment. data is image data with size `sz*sz`. `Unm` is a table of moment which I try to get. `u` is a table size of `n*sz`. usually `n=sz`. My code runs hours to get the reconstruction image, `reimg`. How could I compile this code? All of the arguments are tables of list, that is what confuse me the most. This code is upgrade from this Original code:

```
Do[Unm[[n1, m1]] = 
    Sum[Sum[u[[n1, s]] u[[m1, t]] data[[s, t]], {s, sz}], {t, 
      sz}], {n1, n}, {m1, n}]; 
Do[reimg[[s, t]] = 
    Sum[Sum[ Unm[[n1, m]] u[[n1, s]] u[[m, t]], {n1, n}], {m, n}], {s,
     sz}, {t, sz}];
```

The first code is 2 times faster than the original one, but still not fast enough.Please Help!!!

I try to compile the `Unm` part like this:

```
fc = Compile[{{list1, _Real, 1}, {list2, _Real, 1}}, Unm = list1.list2, 
             Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
Do[list1 = Flatten[Outer[Times, u[[n1]], u[[m1]]]]; list2 = Flatten[data];
  Unm = fc[list1, list2], {n1, n}, {m1, n}];
```

It says:

> Flatten::normal: "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[1.38595258992021`].

What does it mean?

Based on answers below, here is the update code:

```
Unm = u.data.u\[Transpose]; 
reimg1 = u\[Transpose].Unm.u;
```

It's simple. It's elegant. It runs like lightning. Love it. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: It's better if you provide some simple sample data for people to try.

Comment: You might also want to try `Unm=Table[Sum[...],{n1,n},{m1,n}]` as opposed to `Do[Unm ...]` and likewise for the second `Do` loop you've defined for `reimg`.

Comment: Have you looked at `Moments` and/or `CentralMoments`? It looks like you are reproducing  built in function.

Comment: @bills  Yes, I have try Moment, but it doesn't seem like doing what I trying to do here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Map[Flatten, Transpose /@ Outer[Times, u, u], {2}].data` is your `Unm`. Is that a) doing what you want, and b) faster?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Thanks. a) yes, it does.  b)it's not faster.

Comment: A good way to get me used to `Flatten`: `Flatten[Outer[Times, u, u], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}].data // Partition[#, n] &` is also your `Unm`, I think. It won't be very different in speed. Fun, though.

Comment: The error means that one of your `Flatten` calls (probably the `list1` one) is operating on a floating point number, rather than a `List` structure.

Comment: @IPoiler, thanks. Could you tell where did I do wrong?

Comment: Completely impossible to tell without knowing how your variables are defined.

Comment: @IPoiler, here is how I define these tables:`u = Table[0., {n}, {sz}];``Unm = Table[0., {n}, {n}];``data=Table[0,{sz},{sz}]`  I set `n=sz`.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I have a question: why do you use Partition at the end?

Comment: @JanePotter Just because `Flatten` in my example ends up doing one more flattening than is necessary, and `Partition` is an inverse function to `Flatten`. The second argument to `Flatten` sort of combines a `Transpose` with the `Flatten`, which is why I used it.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Compile`  is the toy of experienced *Mathematica* user. You'd better improve your understanding for the core language first. As to your specific question, your attempt can be achieved simply with

```
reimg = u\[Transpose].u.data.u\[Transpose].u;
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I think I should do. The results of compile don't have enough precision in my case anyway, so I think I should try paralize or something else.

Comment: I have try your code, and it is about 40 times faster than mine. That is amazing!!

Comment: But, there is one problem, reimg is supposed to be construct by Unm, instead of data. data is the original image.

Comment: @JanePotter Then simply use `reimg = u\[Transpose].Unm.u;`

Comment: it works!! Now it is 50 times faster!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @JanePotter You can link this post back to Tieba.

Comment: Glad to, but what should I do?

Comment: @JanePotter ……我的意思是你可以把这个帖子的链接也在贴吧那边贴一下，以免有人重复劳动。